# turning a for loop into while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

what is the best way to convert this into a while loop?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                function GetGrades() {
                var grades = [];
                var grade;
                var sum = 0;

                for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
                grade = prompt("Enter Homework " + (i+1) + " grade: ");
                grades.push(Number(grade));
            }
                for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
                document.write("Homework " + (i+1) + " grade: " + grades[i] + "</br>");
            
                sum = sum + grades[i];
            }
                var avg = sum/5.0;
                document.write("</br>Grade: " + avg + "</br>");
            }
            //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="GetGrades()">
    </body>
</html>
```

I have ignorantly tried to simply declare the variable i as sero and change the for to while.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
while(i<5) {
    grade = prompt("Enter Homework " + (i+1) + " grade: ");
    grades.push(Number(grade));
    i++;
}

while(i<5) {

    document.write("Homework " + (i+1) + " grade: " + grades[i] + "</br>");

    sum = sum + grades[i];
    i++;
}
```